# WooCommerce Product Vendors - Assigning Vendor to a product programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Backstory: I am automatically generating a product after a property submission is performed using the [Realteo](https://themeforest.net/item/findeo-real-estate-wordpress-theme/20697875) plugin(baked into the Findeo theme). That is working in its basic form but what I'm having trouble with is assigning a Product Vendor automatically to this newly-generated product.

When I look through the Product Vendors code(official one from WooCommerce.com) I believe the plugin stores the vendor ID as product meta data, the key being `_wcpv_vendor`. However, this doesn't appear to be true; even if I manually edit a product and assign a booking, that key cannot be found when viewing the product's postmeta.

If `_wcpv_vendor` is blank and no vendor is assigned, manually editing that entry does not assign a vendor to a product.

Example from the code of how it attaches the vendor ID to an attachment:

```
public function process_attachment( $post_id ) {
    if ( WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::auth_vendor_user() ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wcpv_vendor', WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_logged_in_vendor() );
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know that I'm making the assumption here that this works the same for products(which is wrong, I know), but I've tried searching through the Product Vendors plugin code and cannot find where exactly the plugin assigns the Vendor ID to a product when a Vendor is added to a product.

Other quick question: Should it be okay to use `WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_logged_in_vendor()` in this scenario to automatically pull the Vendor ID for a user logged into the front-end of the site? I've been trying it but the returned result is blank.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

After digging at this some more, Vendors does not actually directly update the post meta since a Vendor is actually a taxonomy. Instead, when a post is saved, it automatically saves the Vendor ID using wp_set_object_terms